# How to write characteristics for Flutter ble devices?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my project i will have multiple ble devices, (watch, sos button, panic button).

I need to connect to ble device and listen that user click sos button, how i can write characteristic for all that devices?

Now i'm trying to listen like:

```dart
onTapSwitch: () async {
  // Connect to the device
  await device.connect();

  var services = await device.discoverServices();
  for (var service in services) {
    for (var c in service.characteristics) {
      await c.read();
    
      await c.setNotifyValue(true);
      c.value.listen((value) {
        print('Success $value');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But can't get any response, and ble devices automatically disconnects after few seconds of successfully connecting

Comment: What package are you using to connect to the devices?

Comment: flutter_blue_plus

Comment: usually if a BLE device disconnects after a few seconds it requires some action from you to stay connected. This often is the case for products which want to force you to use the manufacturers app. What kind of device is your sos button?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan there will be several ble beacons
1) B10 wrisband 
2) W6 Beacon X pro
3) BlueUp - 10
4) Ibeacon 
Can't we write common characteristic to listen sos buttons click?

Comment: Do you have documentation for the SOS button? it seems like you are not connecting correctly, that's why it disconnects probably

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan no, company sends just devices

Comment: Please try to connect to the device using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile). If it still disconnects after a few seconds you need to ask the manufacturer for more information

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKotzjan, tested with nRF Connect same behavior, will write to manufacturer.